# Example of set which is precompact but not compact

Tags: general-topology

I know that every compact set is precompact but not every precompact set is compact.I can't find an example of precompact set which is not compact .If you know can you enlighten me ?

Comment: $(0,1) $? ${}{}{} $

Comment: Any bounded open interval in $\mathbb R$ will do(for the usual topology).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you

Comment: @ThomasShelby thanks

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Please post this as an answer, so that question can go off the unanswered question queue.

Comment: @ComFreek it has been done ,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb R$, usual topology, $(0,1)$ (or any bounded open interval) is precompact but not compact.